# Defining Boolean Method Ruby Beginner

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, boolean

Back again with a Boolean method definition question for beginners.

Here is the method I'd like to write:

```
def has_booth?
end
```

I'm not quite sure what to pass as the argument.  I want this to return true for users that have created a booth and false for those that haven't.  Booths are associated with a user id and each user can has_one booth. Booths also have a name parameter.

I tried things like

```
booth.id.nil?
```

and

```
booth_id.nil?
```

and

```
booth.name.nil?
```

and

```
booth.name != nil
```

and

```
if current_user
      if session[:booth_id]
```

Can you please guide me as to what I'm doing incorrectly or point me towards some literature?  I have seen a bunch of tutorials for creating simple methods that have simple arguments and return or puts something on a screen, but nothing that seems to help me move the needle.  I'd like to do this as correctly as possible.

If it is helpful, here is my booths controller:

```
class BoothsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user

  def index
    @booths = Booth.all
  end

  def new
    @booth = Booth.new
  end

  def create
    @booth = current_user.build_booth(booth_params)
    if @booth.save
      flash[:success] = "Congrats on opening your booth!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @booth = Booth.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

    def booth_params
      params.require(:booth).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

I appreciate any help or guidance towards a solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Where do you want to put the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `exists?` method:

```
Booth.exists?(user_id: id) # Return true if exists a Booth with user_id == id
```

Your method will look like this:

```
def has_booth?(user_id)
  Booth.exists?(user_id: user_id)
end
```

---

Although, you should put that method in the `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :booth

  def booth? # It's convention booth? instead of has_booth?
    !!self.booth
  end
end
```

Then in your views you could just call the method on your users:

```
<% if current_user.booth? %> ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion.  When I add this code and I include the '<% if has_booth? %>' in my erb I get an error that says "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) 

'Extracted source (around line #3):
1
2
3
4
5
6
                
module BoothsHelper

 def has_booth?(user_id)
  Booth.exists?(user_id: user_id)
end'

Any idea to why this is happening?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to provide an user id. `has_booth?(current_user.id)` might work

Comment: Thanks Mario.  I think that works however I'm still having problems with the erb output.  I might submit it as another question bc I can't find another question like it and it might be helpful to others.  The frustration never ends.

Comment: LOL, that's exactly how I feel.